# Error " No known class method for selector 'canSendTweet'

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am trying to set up a tweet button. All my code seems to be working, except it gives me ther error "No known class method for selector 'canSendTweet'" Any suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)tweetTapped:(id)sender
{
//Check if the device can send tweets
if ([SLComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    //Create tweet sheet and set initial text
   SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet =
    [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"this is a tweet from my app"];
    [tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iosdeveloperguide.com"]];

    //show tweet sheet
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
    //Device can not tweet. Show error Notification.
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Unable to Tweet"
                              message:@"Please ensure that you have at least one Twitter account setup and have internet connectivity"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertview show];

}

}


 @end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such class method named `canSendTweet` for the class `SLComposeViewController`. A quick look at the reference docs (which you should have done) reveals that what you want is:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    // can send a tweet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canSendTweet
```

That is a method from Twitter.framework (you must import this framework)

and you can use this method in Social.framework to check "Can user tweet ?"

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    // can send a tweet
}
```